# Calling Function using string with parameters inside the function in c#

Tags: c#

Hello guys I want to add parameters inside this function send() but I don`t know how to make it work

```
string function = "send"; 
Type type = this.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(function);
methodInfo.Invoke(this,null);
```

Comment: Where you've written `null`; that's where the parameters go

Comment: aa now it worked! haha thank you so much! I thought I just do it like this

methodinfo.Invoke(this, "hello");
it should be like this
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new Object[] { "hello" });

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP <3

Comment: If anyone asking my problem also, here is the solution
Wrong: 
methodinfo.Invoke(this, "hello");
Corrrect: 
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new Object[] { "hello" });

Answer (score 2):

If anyone asking my problem also, here is the solution

Wrong:

```
methodinfo.Invoke(this, "hello");
```

Correct:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new Object[] { "hello" });
```